# How to get content from a <li> and place it in a jQuery array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to get the content of a list and place it in an array. As a result I get a list of numbers instead of the content its self. Any ideas how I can place the content in the array instead?

```
var ar = [];


$('.div-holder .tab-inner').each(function(){

  var createList = (ar.push($(this.innerHTML).text()));
  console.log(createList);

});

<div class="div-holder">


<ul><li class="tab-alpha"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Beverley</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-beta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Driffield</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-gamma"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Francis Scaife</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-delta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Goole</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-epsilon tab-selected"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Haltemprice</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-zeta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Hornsea</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-eta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">South Cave</span></span></a></li><li class="tab-theta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">South Holderness</span></span></a></li>
<li class="tab-iota">
<a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#">
<span class="tab-outer">
<span class="tab-inner">Withernsea</span>
</span>
</a>
```

Here is a link to the issue https://jsfiddle.net/ryadkhhp/4/

Comment: Where do want to get the valu in ar array or createList ? if arr then your one is ok. Just console.log(ar) or if you want to print it in createList  then assign it as createList = $(this).html();

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6rhghfh/

```
var ar = [];
$('.div-holder .tab-inner').each(function(){
        ar.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(ar)
```

Output:

```
 ["Beverley", "Driffield", "Francis Scaife", "Goole", "Haltemprice", "Hornsea", "South Cave", "South Holderness", "Withernsea"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to asign `.push()` method result to `createList`, and `.push` returns array length, that is way you are getting numbers instead of text.

Secondly you are using `$` in wrong way - it should accept selector or DOM element, and you are passing text node. You should use `ar.push(this.innerHTML)` or `ar.push($(this).text())`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ar = [];
  var ar2 = [];

  $('.div-holder .tab-inner').each(function() {
    ar.push($(this).text());
  });
  
  document.write(ar)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-holder">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-alpha"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Beverley</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-beta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Driffield</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-gamma"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Francis Scaife</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-delta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Goole</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-epsilon tab-selected"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Haltemprice</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-zeta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">Hornsea</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-eta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">South Cave</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-theta"><a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#"><span class="tab-outer"><span class="tab-inner">South Holderness</span></span></a></li>
    <li class="tab-iota">
      <a href="/promotions/half-term-activities/#">
        <span class="tab-outer">
<span class="tab-inner">Withernsea</span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryadkhhp/5/).

If you want to need the whole html context then just print by it

```
console.log(ar);
```

or if you want to get it in createList then do like this

```
$('.div-holder .tab-inner').each(function(){
var createList = (ar.push($(this).text()));
createList = $(this).text();
console.log(createList);
});
```